# how do i calculate the end time of appointment when i know length of the service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, nested-forms

I have two models, Services and Appointments. A Service can have many appointments.

I have a nested form for users to book appointments.

How can I have the end time of the appointment automatically calculated? Understandably, I'd rather not rely on the user to enter an end time based on the length of the Service they have selected.

Currently my controller looks like this...

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_appointment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :load_services, only: [:new, :edit]
  after_filter :end_calculate, only: [:create, :update]

  [...]

  # POST /appointments
  # POST /appointments.json
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.save
       # redirect_to root_url
        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /appointments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /appointments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  [...]

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_appointment
      @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def appointment_params
      params.require(:appointment).permit(:start_time, :end_time, :note, :service_id)
    end

    def load_services
      @services = Service.all.collect {|service| [ service.title, service.length, service.id] }
    end

    def end_calculate
      @appointment.end_time = @appointment.start_time + @service.length.minutes
      @appointment.end_time.save
    end

end
```

Comment: what type is length?

Comment: its an integer. the number represents how many minutes the service will last. So it could be 30, 60, 90, etc.

Comment: i assume start_time is a type of Time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a discussion the solution is to remove the `end_calculate` method from controller, and to add `end_time` method to Appointment class:

```
  def end_time
    end_time = self.start_time + self.service.length.minutes
  end
```